# select and remove multiple images with preview before upload

Tags: javascript, php, image, plugins

I'm looking for a plugin which allows adding multiple images, previewing, removing and submitting with some extra fields without ajax.

i have found some very good plugins like fineUploader and dropzone but they submit with ajax. with these plugins i haven't figured out how to submit without ajax.

Comment: Plugins for? What framework or programming language

Comment: why you don't want ajax? You don't understand ajax?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile  i dont want ajax bacause the images will be submitted to next page where i will get detail information regarding each image like its name, location etc

Comment: I can assist with the preview part, my only challenge is the remove part

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile do you know about any plugin that provides the functionality?

Comment: You can use Jquery to preview the selected images

Comment: If you can limit your users to HTML5 only then you can use HTML5 features to read and display the selected images without having to upload: http://codepedia.info/html5-filereader-preview-image-show-thumbnail-image-before-uploading-on-server-in-jquery/ If you have to support browsers that don't support HTML5 then you'll need Flash or something else.

Comment: @akmalsaeed check my answer below, option 2 might be close to what you want, its jquery then wrote some functions

Answer (score 5):

> **I'm looking for a plugin which allows adding `multiple images`, `previewing`, removing and submitting with some extra fields without
>   ajax.**

**multiple images** ----> `<input type='file' id="myfiles" multiple="multiple" name="files[]">`

**previewing** ---> Jquery

**removing**-----> Highly impossible to remove one by one image from file list,as the api is read only,however we can  clear the entire file list, when the remove button is clicked.

**without ajax** ----> Just action the form to the controller/handler.

I don't think there's a way to achieve what you need beside using one of the plugins you have mentioned above.

You have 2 Options that I can think of currently.

1. use the multiple attribute on the file input type, then u can be able to use jquery to preview the images that are loaded but however we can not remove the image one by one from the `filelist` we can only remove the image from the preview but the server side still gonna process the image, or we can just clear the entire filelist, as I have mentioned above.

**OR**

1. we can add the `file` field dynamically using jquery, in this way we can be able to add one image add a time, then have an add more images button that will append a new `file` input to our form, with this we will be able to remove images one by one before processing in the server side.

**Option 1**

```js
 $('document').ready(function() {
        var images = function(input, imgPreview) {
    
            if (input.files) {
                var filesAmount = input.files.length;
    
                for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
    
                    reader.onload = function(event) {
                        $($.parseHTML("<img class='pic'>")).attr('src', event.target.result).appendTo(imgPreview);
                    }
                    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
                }
            }
    
        };
    
        $('#myimg').on('change', function() {
            images(this, '#previews');
        });
            
            //clear the file list when image is clicked
        $('body').on('click','img',function(){
            $('#myimg').val("");
            $('#previews').html("");
    
        });
    });
```

```css
 img{
    cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form id="form1"  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="server.php" method="post">
    <input type='file' id="myimg" multiple="multiple">
    <div id="previews"></div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Option 2**

```js
var abc = 0;
        $('#add_more').click(function ()
            {
                $(this).before($("<div/>",{id: 'filediv'}).fadeIn('slow').append($("<input/>",
                            {
                                name: 'file[]',
                                type: 'file',
                                id: 'file'
                            }),
                            $("<br/><br/>")
                        ));
            });
        $('body').on('change', '#file', function ()
            {
                if (this.files && this.files[0])
                {
                    abc += 1; //increementing global variable by 1
                    var z = abc - 1;
                    var x = $(this)
                        .parent()
                        .find('#previewimg' + z).remove();
                    $(this).before("<div id='abcd" + abc + "' class='abcd'><img id='previewimg" + abc + "' src=''/></div>");
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
                    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
                    $(this)
                        .hide();
                    $("#abcd" + abc).append($("<img/>",{
                                id: 'img',
                                src: 'x.png', //the remove icon
                                alt: 'delete'
                            }) .click(function ()
                            {
                                $(this)
                                    .parent()
                                    .parent()
                                    .remove();
                            }));
                }
            });
        //image preview
        function imageIsLoaded(e)
        {
            $('#previewimg' + abc)
                .attr('src', e.target.result);
        };
```

```html
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form method="POST" action="server.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
            <div id="filediv"><input name="file[]" type="file" id="file"/></div>
    <input type="button" id="add_more" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add More Files"/><br><br>
    
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I believe this more esp option 2 can do the trick, select image, add more preview delete, then when u are happy hit the submit button then do your processing on the server. You might add styling to the preview images

Goodluck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DropzoneJS](http://www.dropzonejs.com/)

They have a list of configurable options that you can find here. [Dropzone JS Usage.](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#usage)

If you still need more customization then you will have to add your own code to it. Hope this helps you from writing thousand lines of code.

**Without AJAX requests:**

This may help you. [Click here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23716048/non-ajax-post-using-dropzone-js)

Comment: *i have found some very good plugins like fineUploader and dropzone but they submit with ajax. with these plugins i haven't figured out how to submit without ajax.*

Comment: Then it may require us to write our own plugin ;)