# Dropzone.js - I can't upload my images

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, dropzone

I made a controller which works correctly:

```
    public function gallerystore(Request $request){
    $gallery_path = 'uploads';
    $files = $request->file('gallery');
    foreach ($files as $gallery) {
      $gallery_new_name = time().$gallery->getClientOriginalName();
      $gallery->move($gallery_path, $gallery_new_name);

      $img = Image::make(public_path($gallery_path . '/' .$gallery_new_name));
      $img->resize(null, 720, function($constraint){
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
      });
    }
}
```

Problem is when i try use `Dropzone.js`. Actually when I added class *dropzone* into form. Laravel show me error

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach().

Answer (score 0):

I think adding the HTML code would help to further debug the issue. However, the error seems to be happening because the `gallery` parameter that you are trying to fetch is null, thus the `foreach` method is not able to iterate through this value.

I would suggest that the reason why this parameter is null is due to the fact that the form being submitted lacks the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` needed for the upload to work. Check both without the plugin and with it that this attribute is set.

Comment: I doesn;t show my markup but I have enctype="multipart/form-data". But in docs I saw that configuration this librari looks like ajax. You have to give url and so on. So it works asynchronous. But it's not good way in my case.

Comment: @theexpanse87 Yes, for security reasons no js can modify what it is on a file input. If you still wish to perform a non-ajax request using Dropzone, you will need to serialize the file or an equivalent approach, i.e https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23716048/non-ajax-post-using-dropzone-js